# adding startup script to dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have built my docker image using openjdk.

```
# config Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:8
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

# build image
docker build -t shantanuo/dbt .
```

It is working as expected using this command...

```
docker run -p 8081:8080  -it shantanuo/dbt
```

Once I log-in, I have to run this command...

```
sh bin/startup.sh
```

---

My Question: Is it possible to add the startup command to dockerfile? I tried adding this line in my dockerfile.

```
CMD ["sh", "bin/startup.sh"]
```

But after building the image, I can not use -d parameter to start the container.

Comment: "I can not use -d parameter to start the container": why? Maybe your startup script exits too early. The container stops when the command exits.

Comment: How do I keep the command running? In other words, I do not want the container to exit after starting tomcat service. The shell script works correctly without docker.

Comment: If it's tomcat you are starting use `CMD ["bin/catalina.sh", "run"]`

Comment: When you run the script manually, does it run the tomcat in background and come back to the bash shell?

Comment: TarunLalwani yes, it does. @Henry yes, adding your CMD to dockerfile worked. I have not modified startup.sh file. So I guess it is OK to skip it. Right?

Comment: @shantanuo yes, startup.sh basically does the same, but starts the process in background. I am not completely sure (too lazy to confirm) but I think startup.sh uses catalina.sh internally as well.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to run the startup script. In the entrypoint you can specify your custom script, and then run `catlina.sh`.

Example:

```
ENTRYPOINT "bin/startup.sh && catalina.sh run"
```

This will run your startup script and then start your tomcat server, and it won't exit the container.

Comment: @Henry I have added an example to demonstrate usage of entrypoint. This uses exec form of entrypoint. There is an alternate thing which he can do, which is to append the `catlina.sh run` command towards the end of startup script.

Comment: I have used similar thing in [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/reactome/container/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml) and I *think* I have correctly written equivalent syntax for dockerfile.

Answer (score 4):

This is addressed in the documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

If one of your processes depends on the main process, then start your helper process FIRST with a script like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), then start the main process SECOND and remove the `fg %1` line.

```
#!/bin/bash
  
# turn on bash's job control
set -m
  
# Start the primary process and put it in the background
./my_main_process &
  
# Start the helper process
./my_helper_process
  
# the my_helper_process might need to know how to wait on the
# primary process to start before it does its work and returns
  
  
# now we bring the primary process back into the foreground
# and leave it there
fg %1
```

Answer (score 1):

A docker container must have a dedicated task. It is important that this task/startup script does not terminate. When it does, the task is done and everything for docker is done right.

It makes no sense to start a container only with the JDK. You have to put your application in it.

I think it would help when you will post what you exactly want to do.

The Docker reference is always a good place to look at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint