# How can I run a searchguard set up script after elasticsearch is up and running in docker?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, dockerfile, search-guard

I have been trying to make the searchguard setup script `init_sg.sh` to run after elasticsearch automatically. I don't want to do it manually with `docker exec`. Here's what I have tried.

entrypoint.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
elasticsearch
source init_sg.sh
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.1.0

COPY config/ config/
COPY bin/ bin/

# Search Guard plugin
# https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard/wiki
RUN elasticsearch-plugin install --batch com.floragunn:search-guard-6:6.1.0-20.1 \
    && chmod +x \
        plugins/search-guard-6/tools/hash.sh \
        plugins/search-guard-6/tools/sgadmin.sh \
    && chown -R elasticsearch config/sg/ \
    && chmod -R go= config/sg/


#  This custom entrypoint script is used instead of 
# the original's /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["bash","-c","entrypoint.sh"]
```

However, it'd throw `cannot run elasticsearch as root error`:

```
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
```

So I guess I cannot run elasticsearch directly in `entrypoint.sh`, which is confusing because there's no problem when the Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.1.0

COPY config/ config/
COPY bin/ bin/
....
CMD ["elasticsearch"]
```

This [thread's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671589/how-can-i-run-script-automatically-after-docker-container-startup/47671839#47671839) accepted answer doesn't work. There's no "/run/entrypoint.sh" in the container.

**Solution**:

Finally I've managed to get it done. Here's my custom entrypoint script that will run the searchguard setup script automatically:

```
source init_sg.sh

while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
   sleep 10
   source init_sg.sh
done &

/bin/bash -c "source /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh;"
```

If you have any alternative solutions, please feel free to answer.

Comment: Have you tried removing last line ENTRYPOINT ["bash","-c","entrypoint.sh"] - from Dockerfile and then just run your post install script in Dockerfile using RUN command like 'RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html'

Comment: @techtrainer the setup script has to be executed after elasticsearch starts up. `RUN` would actually run the command during the build, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: see also https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/tree/searchguard